# Slide Div on hover from right in a positioned div

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have the following Situation:
A centered Div layer holding the content.
In the bottom right edge, there is a positioned div `(bottom: 0, right: 0)` with two elements, a link and a linklist. The linklist should be hidden.
When you hover the Link, it should be moved leftly and the linklist should slide in.
How to i make this:

CSS:

```
#page {
 position: relative;
} 
#linkholder {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 10px;
 right: 0px;
}
#link {
 display: inline-block;
}
#linklist {
 display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
  content
  <div id="linkholder">
    <div id="link">Link</div>
    <div id="linklist">LINKS TO SLIDE IN WHEN HOVER LINK</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a css transition. This could look like this:

```
#linklist {
    /* Set the animation and speed */
    /*general version*/
    transition: all 5s;
    /*browser specific versions*/
    -moz-transition: all 5s;
    -ms-transition: all 5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 5s;
    -o-transition: all 5s;
}
#linklist.hidden {
    /* Have it translated off the screen first*/
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(100px, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(100px, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(100px, 0);
    transform: translate(100px, 0);
}
```

Then you make a callback in javascript which sets the class for the #linklist when hovering over the #link.

```
var event = function () {
    document.getElementById('linklist').className = '';
    this.removeEventListener('mouseover', event);
};
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('mouseover', event, true);
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XWReQ/

Comment: Also, if you want it hidden at first, just add opacity:0 to #linklist.hidden.